# (MAUI) Access programmatically to Shell.FlyoutItems

Tags: c#, collections, maui, flyout

I'm try to access from code to my FlyoutItems

```
    <classes:BCTab Title="Home"  FlyoutIcon="home24.png" Tag="DASHBOARD">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DashboardPage}" />
    </classes:BCTab>
    <classes:BCTab Title="Servizi"  FlyoutIcon="camera24.png" Tag="SERVICES" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ServicesPage}" />
    </classes:BCTab>
    <classes:BCTab Title="Change Password"  FlyoutIcon="password24.png" Tag="CHGPASSWOR">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ChangePasswordPage}" />
    </classes:BCTab>
</FlyoutItem>`
```

BCTab is a derived class from Tab with some properties added

in c# I wrote

```
 foreach (var item in this.FlyoutItems)
 {
   // now here???   
 }
```

I wanna show or hide the tab element.. permission cames from a REST service that gives me a code (one of the added properties in a List < string >).. it would be simple if I can access to a BCTab element via "item.controls" or "item.childelements" (or somewhat similiar) but I'm unable to understand how to do and all my searches are vain.

Any suggestion?

In debug look at item class and properties, searched on google and MS documentation

Comment: why don't you bind them to properties of your VM and set their visibility that way?

Comment: @Jason I think is easier to iterate through a collection and verify in a code is present than to set a lot of binded properties
'
foreach (item in collection)
{
    item.visible=list.contains(item.Tag);
}
'
easy, ins't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this. It ended up being easier than I believed.

```
foreach (IEnumerable item in this.FlyoutItems) 
{
    foreach (BCTab tab in item.ToList<BCTab>()) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(tab.Tag); 
    }
}
```

`Flyoutitems` is an `IEnumerable` of objects (the same container in XAML between his marking tags). In my specific case, I know they are all of `BCTab` (the class I derived from `Tab`), so I use the `ToList <BCTab>()` extension.

In a more generic way, it's possibile to use `ToList<object>()` or `ToList<View>()` and thus verifying the correct type (usually `Tab`). With a simple cast of the object, it's then possible to work on the object.